# Reading all txt files from a folder

Tags: python, text

I am trying to open  100+ txt files in a specific folder, named txt. each .txt file in txt folder is expected to move into an NLP procedure with the following code.

```
import nltk.data
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('averaged_perceptron_tagger')
sent_detector = nltk.data.load('tokenizers/punkt/english.pickle')
import types
import pandas as pd

txt='../sec_cleaning/txt/' #path of txt folder including all txt files
rid=0
for A_2_2018_12_20 in txt:
    sentences = {}
    sentences[rid] = []
    sentences[rid].extend(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip()))
    rid+=1
sentences = {}
sentences[rid] = []
sentences[rid].extend(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip()))
```

However, I keep getting this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-3e2ea464f107> in <module>
      3     sentences = {}
      4     sentences[rid] = []
----> 5     sentences[rid].extend(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip()))
      6     rid+=1

NameError: name 'text' is not defined
```

Comment: You haven't declared any `text` variable, maybe `A_2_2018_12_20` should be renamed as `text`.

Comment: Actually, you don't read any file.

Comment: In addition your for loop over what you have for txt won't do what you think. It will iterate over the characters in the string of that path. You should read up on `pathlib` module.

Comment: Thanks for these great comments. Yes, I want to read and iterate for all txt files in the folder through pushing each .txt file into NLP procedure. any  suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is:

1. loop over all `.txt` file in the folder `../sec_cleaning/txt/`
2. for each text file: read it, and loop over each line.
3. for each line: parse the sentences and add them to the `sentences` list.

Here is a draft:

```py
import pathlib

text_dir = pathlib.Path('../sec_cleaning/txt/')

sentences = []
for text_path in text_dir.glob("*.txt"):
    for line in text_path.read_text(encoding="utf-8"):
        line = line.strip()
        sentences.extend(sent_detector.tokenize(line)))
```

Comment: Hi Laurent, thanks for your help. I keep getting" IndexError: list index out of range" error. do you have any idea, why?

Comment: Oops! you need to use `extend`. See my edit

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because `text` is indeed not defined. As you can see in your loop, you have `A_2_2018_12_20`, yet you never used it. Change `A_2_2018_12_20` to `text` and it should work.

```
for text in txt:
    sentences = {}
    sentences[rid] = []
    sentences[rid].extend(sent_detector.tokenize(text.strip()))
    rid+=1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here, i remember using this before. the basic idea is to open the folder & count how many texts are there and you can display them or do what ever you want!
Here's a sample:

```
import os 
counting_texts = sum(len(files) for _, _, files in os.walk(r'path/to/folder'))
```

After that you can easily manipulate them